# Android mock restful service created using retrofit 2 and rxjava?

Tags: mocking, retrofit, rx-java, android-testing

I am trying to mock REST response for my Android App. Retrofit 2 and RxJava are used to implement network calls and these are new to me.

I was successfully able to mock using the tutorial [here](http://riggaroo.co.za/retrofit-2-mocking-http-responses/) by using mockwebserver.

However, since it does not use Observable, mockwebserver does not register the call, I think.

My interface looks like this:

```
@POST("auth/token")
Observable<authenticationaccess> authenticate(
@Query("username") String username,
@Query("password") String password,
@Query("grant_type") String grantType,
@Query("scope") String scope);
```

And I call like this,

```
server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
.setResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
.setBody("{}"));
```

I found a few tutorials that use Dagger which required lots of coding for such a small thing. Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    server = new MockWebServer();
    server.start();
    NetworkServiceHelper.init(String.valueOf(server.url("/")));
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR));
```